# XRDP on Centos7 work differently on different accounts

Tags: windows-10, macos, remote-desktop, centos-7

I have a server running Centos7 and have xrdp-0.9.10 installed. I keep all xrdp setting to default. I want to login in the server from windows or macos.

I have 7 user accounts (for example, user01-07), and all can login in through the remote desktop software on Windows 10 except one account, user02. When I type in the user02 and password, attempt to login ... the software exits immediately. Other accounts work properly on the same computer.

I tried using the Microsoft Remote Desktop beta app on MacOS. The question is still there. However, the client shows: Your session ended because of a data encryption error. If this keeps happening, contact your network administrator for assistance.

Error code: 0x407

So, any suggestions will help. How can I debug it?

Comment: What do you mean by Microsoft Remote Desktop **beta** app?  Have you tried [Microsoft Remote Desktop 10](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop-10/id1295203466) or [Microsoft Remote Desktop 8](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop-8/id715768417) from the App Store?  Do either of these work?

Comment: I use Microsoft Remote Desktop beta app because I can not get Microsoft Remote Desktop from App Store, as it is not there in Chinese Mainland App Store. But, I think I am using the same one. You can find more info on: https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/5e0c144289a51fca2d3bfa39ce7f2b06/

Comment: That looks to be the same - 10.2.13 is the current version of Remote Desktop 10 from App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the answer.
The user02 account has set DISPLAY to localhost:0 in .bashrc file, and this is the reason!
Unset DISPLAY using `unset DISPLAY` and everything is ok now.